# A strange HTML display issue when mix use Arabian character (right to left) with normal English character

Tags: html, special-characters, currency, right-to-left

Here's [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/benb88/SJkYw/2/) I created to demonstrate the problem.

The output of following code seems to be wrong

```
<pre>
    <div>
        <span>Exchange Rate : 1 AED(د.إ)</span><span> = 1.0 EUR(€)</span>
    </div>
</pre>
```

while display can be correct if I change it to 2 lines.

```
<pre>
    <div>
        <span>Exchange Rate : 1 AED(د.إ)</span>
        <br />
        <span> = 1.0 EUR(€)</span>
    </div>
</pre>
```

Hope some nice guy can figure out this strange problem. Even appreciate more if there are some background knowledge you can share to us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well it is problem with rtl languages and rtl languages

```
<div>
    <span>Exchange Rate : 1 USD($)</span>
    <span> = 1.0 EUR(€)</span>
</div>
<div>
    <div class="en">Exchange Rate : 1 AED<div class="ar">(د.إ)</div>  = 1.0 EUR(€)</div>
</div>
```

try to fix by putting another language in separate element give it `direction:rtl;` and in [this case](http://jsfiddle.net/SJkYw/3/) i gave `display:inline-block;`